# References to uncompiled sections

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling, comments

Im writing my thesis with latex and I used different files for the chapters, inserted in the main one with the \input command.

Sometimes, I need to compile just 1 chapter (to send it to a reader, or to see rapidly the modifications that im doing). To do so, i comment/uncomment the related "input" commands.

But i would like to keep in the compiled chapter, the cross-references to the uncompiled chapters (sections, figures, tables,...). If i do first a compilation of the whole document, is it possible to keep the cross-references after, by avoiding destroying the old toc file, are something like that ?

Im using cleverref, but i dont know if it is useful for the present issue.

A MWE is not very usefull, but it could be as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

%\section{Uncompiled section}\label{thelabel}
%Hello world!

\section{Compiled section}
See \cref{thelabel} to get the Hello World.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can separate your document into several subfiles using `\includeonly` and `\include`. There are several explanations about how to use it on the net as well as how to avoid pagebreaks that are inserted automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\include` set of commands. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\includeonly{chap1,chap3} % only process chap1.tex and chap3.tex
\begin{document}
\include{chap1}    % input chap1.tex
\include{chap2}    % input chap2.tex
\include{chap3}    % input chap3.tex
\include{chap4}    % input chap4.tex
\end{document}
```

which will only process chap1.tex and chap3.tex but will keep all crossreferences to previously included files. To process the whole lot comment out the `\includeonly` macro.

Comment: god this is so simple !

Comment: And the page numbers are kept as well! incredible